# passing value to function

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass by reference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998209/pass-by-reference-in-java)

I am new to java. I tried to search a lot for my query but could not find. Please help me if you know. I have a function:

```
boolean func(int a, int b, myclass obj1, myclass2 obj2)
{
    ...
}

void caller() {
    int a = 0, b=0;
    myclass obj1 = null;
    myclass1 obj2 = null;
    func(a,b,obj1,obj2);
    if (a == 5 && b ==2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

what should i do such that all passed variables have the value in caller function which was given by function func?

Comment: Java passes by value, so everything passed from `caller` to `func` is a copy (of primitives or references). Can you explain what you are really doing in `func`, so that we can come up with better approaches to what you're trying to do?

Comment: You already asked this question and it was closed as a duplicate last time too.

Comment: @JohnB Yikes... Good duplicate detective work. One dupe, okay. But trying it again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use pass-by-reference and use that to change the values of your variables through `func`. That can't be done in Java. It's strictly pass-by-value. Even when passing an object as a parameter, what you're actually passing is the reference value. So doing this:

```
func(Object o) {
    o = "test";
}
...
other() {
    Object a = new Object();
    func(a);
}
```

... won't have altered the `a` reference. It's still pointing to that Object instance rather than String "test". Method `func` has merely overwritten the local variable `o` that was given the reference value of `a` when it was called.

I suggest you either encapsulate your variables in some class that you pass into your method, or return from the method that takes an argument list, or rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not work that way. When `a` and `b` are passed to `func`, copies are made. `func` can change the values of those copies internally, but when it returns, the original `a` and `b` will be unchanged.

I don't know what `a` and `b` represent, but lets say they are coordinates. You can do this:

```
class Coordinates {
  int x;
  int y;
  // setters and getters omitted...
}

boolean func(Coordinates coords, myclass obj1, myclass2 obj2) {
...
}
```

Or since they start out as zero, perhaps this:

```
Coordinates func(myclass obj1, myclass2 obj2) {
  Coordinates coords = new Coordinates();
  ...
  return coords;
}
```